# formatting datetime for json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, datetime

I have a view file (show.json.erb) that's displaying my @step model attributes, and I'd like to format the DateTime attribute "published_on".  With my current implementation, I get the error:

```
undefined method `strftime' for :published_on:Symbol
```

Here is my code:

```
{ 
    "success":true, 
    "info":"ok", 
    "data":
        { "step":
            <%= JSON.pretty_generate(@step.as_json(only: [:name, :description, :id, :last, :position, :published_on.strftime("%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")], include: {images: {only: [:file, :position] } } )).html_safe %>
    } 
}
```

Any ideas for how to fix this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by defined an attribute in my model:

```
def formatted_date
  published_on.strftime("%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")
end
```

Then I referenced it in my json file:

```
<%= JSON.pretty_generate(@step.as_json(only: [:name, :description, :id, :last], methods: :formatted_date, include: {images: {only: [:file, :position] } } )).html_safe %>
```